# iText not returning text contents of a PDF after first page

Tags: itext

I am trying to use the iText library with c# to capture the text portion of pdf files.

I created a pdf from excel 2013 (exported) and then copied the sample from the web of how to use itext (added the lib ref to the project).

It reads perfectly the first page but it gets garbled info after that. It is keeping part of the first page and merging the info with the next page. The commented lines is when I was trying to solve the problem, the string "thePage" is recreated inside the for loop.

Here is the code. I can email the pdf to whoever can help with this issue.

Thanks in advance

```
   public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
    {

        ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            //string[] theLines;
            //theLines = new string[COLUMNS];
            //string thePage;

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                string thePage = "";
                thePage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its);

                string [] theLines = thePage.Split('\n');
                foreach (var theLine in theLines)
                {
                    text.AppendLine(theLine);
                }
             //   text.AppendLine(" ");
            //    Array.Clear(theLines, 0, theLines.Length);
            //    thePage = "";
            }
            return text.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a new strategy object for each page. A strategy object collects text data and does not know if a new page has started or not.

Comment: Thanks, I instantiated the its object inside the loop and that solved the problem. I know I am supposed to "upvote" on an answer that solves the problem but I don't know how. Anyways thanks for you good and prompt response.

Comment: I only created a comment, not an answer. I'll make that an explicit answer, and you can accept that answer by clicking the mark on the left side of it.

Answer (score 0):

A strategy object collects text data and does not know if a new page has started or not.

Thus, use a new strategy object for each page.

Comment: Sorry, I have to have 15 reputations to vote up. Thanks anyways

Comment: Upvoting is not necessary, but accepting would be appropriate.

Comment: I definitely accept your answer, if there is a procedure to "accept" the answer I ,once again, am ignorant of it. I do value the resources I come across on the site but I work in a small shop and have to wear many hats so I never took a tour on how to exercise the proper "etiquette". Regardless of it you did save me some time with my project.